# "Due to heavy load, the latest workflow operation has been queued." show up in ALL workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, performance

Our SP2010 farm have been used for 5 years. In recent few months, we find all the workflow shows up red warning message "Due to heavy load, the latest workflow operation has been queued. It will attempt to resume at a later time." regardless which workflow and when it is run. We tested in mid-night for a simple workflow the message also show.

Also we found all workflows are running slow compare to 1 year before. We have retention policy setup for workflow history (delete after 3 months). Is there anything we can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may mean the RAM is limited. Also check these variables:

- Increase Throttle Size
- Increase Batch Size
- Time Out
- Workflow Timer Interval
- AutoCleanUpDays

Grabbed from here: https://praveenkasireddy.wordpress.com/2013/06/14/workflow-due-to-heavy-load-the-latest-workflow-operation-has-been-queued-it-will-attempt-to-resume-at-a-later-time/